# Calculate $e^A$ where $A \in M_{2\times 2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convergence-divergence, power-series

Let  $A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\ 
-1& 0 
\end{pmatrix}$ calculate $e^A$.

i find the jordan form of $A$ and i said that $A \sim \begin{pmatrix}
i & 0 \\ 
0& -i 
\end{pmatrix}=B$

so $e^A\sim e^B$

then from the algebra of that diagonal matrix $B$ we can say that $e^B= \begin{pmatrix}
 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{i^n}{n!}& 0 \\ 
0&\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{(-i)^n}{n!} 
\end{pmatrix}$

Can I find where $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{i^n}{n!}$ converges? Or do I leave it such as ?

Comment: The series for the exponential of a square matrix always converges; it can serve as its definition. On the other hand, knowing just $\exp(B)$ won't tell you the value of $\exp(A)$.

Comment: This is correct but doesn't help me to calculate the sum.

Comment: More important if my method is incorrect how do I calculate $e^A$ if I can't find the powers of that matrix?

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{i^n}{n!}=e^i =\cos(1) + i \sin (1)$$

where the second equality is due to $\exp(\theta i ) = \cos(\theta)+i\sin\theta$. Similarly,

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-i)^n}{n!}=e^{-i} =\cos(1) - i \sin (1)$$

To compute $e^A$, consider the eigenvectors too.

Comment: Thank you ! Of course, it was the Taylor series I forgot about.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on ''To compute $e^A$, consider the eigenvectors too'' because my professor didn't show us how to solve questions like that yet I am been called to solve them somehow ; I tried using the things I learn, but clearly I failed to do so and here I am to ask for some help, so I could understand it. If you could help me a little more I would appreciate it.

Comment: You have found $A=P^{-1}BP$ for some $P$ right. So we have $e^A=P^{-1}e^BP$.

Comment: ok i see it now thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using that $A^2=-I$, you can write
$\exp(A)=\sum_{k\in\Bbb N}\frac{A^k}{k!}
 =\sum_{l\in\Bbb N}\frac{(-1)^l}{(2l)!}I+\sum_{l\in\Bbb N}\frac{(-1)^l}{(2l+1)!}A
$.
You should be able to find nice expressions for those two numerical summations. Then you can write out the precise matrix, which you should be able to recognise.

Comment: I understand that thank you for answering. Is the method you used above a general method to solve those types of questions (find $e^A ect$) or this only work for that case ? Because if the polynomial is more complicated i am not sure is this would work.

Comment: Is this right? $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}=\frac{1}{2}e^{-1}$

Comment: No, the series for $\exp$ has $n!$ in the denominator; as the parentheses indicate $(2n)!$ is not the same as (and a lot bigger than) $2n!$. Think about the series for $\cos$ instead.

Answer (score 1):

By Cayley-Hamilton, $A^2=-I.$  Let
$$e^{At}=\alpha I+\beta A$$ for functions
$\alpha$ and $\beta$ of $t.$
$${d\over dt}e^{At}=\alpha' I+\beta' A =Ae^{At}=$$  $$\alpha A + \beta (-I)=-\beta I + \alpha A.$$
Therefore, $\alpha'=-\beta$ and $\beta'=\alpha$ so that $\alpha$ is the solution of
$$(D^2-1)y=0;\ y(0)=1,\ y'(0)=0.$$
$$\text{Therefore, }\ \alpha={1\over 2}(e^t+e^{-t}) \ \ \text{and}$$ $$\beta = -\alpha' =-{1\over 2}(e^t-e^{-t}).$$
Replace $t$ by $1$ to get $e^A.$